# Password for authentication

Tags: dual-boot, software-installation

I am new to Ubuntu. I don't know my password to authentication for dowloading applications in appstore. How I get password for authentication to download apps ?

Comment: The password is the same password you use to login. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in as root with 
`sudo su` 
`sudo -i` 
and then using the `passwd` command change the root password.